# Why floating div-s go even out of parenting div-s?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style bubble chat with the following:

```
.bubble{
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px #B2B2B2;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.bubble::before {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    content: "\00a0";
    display: block;
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 11px;
    transform:             rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
    -moz-transform:    rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
    -ms-transform:     rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
    -o-transform:      rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
    -webkit-transform: rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
    width:  20px;
}

.human {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 45px 5px 20px;
}

.human::before {
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px 0 rgba( 178, 178, 178, .4 );
    left: -9px;
}

.bot {
    float: right;
    margin: 5px 20px 5px 45px;
}

.bot::before {
    box-shadow: 2px -2px 2px 0 rgba( 178, 178, 178, .4 );
    right: -9px;
}
```

Unfortunately, if chat is too wide, sayings of one side starts to go into one row.

[image]

I was trying to stop this with enclosing pairs of phrases into separate divs

```
<div class="sayanswerpair">
      <div class="humanphrase human bubble">Hi!</div>
      <div class="botphrase bot bubble" id="botphrase1">Hi it's great to see you!</div>
   </div>
```

but this didn't help.

Code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/dimskraft/fk4wcsx2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, just add `clear: both;` to your `.bubble` selector in your CSS. That should get the desired effect.

Quick Note: When a parent container's children are floated, the parent container collapses. Although you don't need this, this can be prevented by adding `overflow:hidden;` to the parent selector.

Comment: overflow hidden would work fine, but any absolute children going past their parent would get cut off (not saying that is the case here, but why make it a constraint!)

Comment: Yes, in this case is not necessary, but in others it could be. You may need to add the constraint if you need to have a background added to the parent or perhaps some children text does need hidden with absolute positioning for accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to use the **[clearfix](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)** selector on the **.sayanswerpair** class grouping because elements are floating within that parent. See below for change:

**CSS**

```
// clearfix solution: makes it so inner elements on grouping cannot float out of parent and cause float issues with other elements
.sayanswerpair:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
}

// not needed, but makes the last phrase in the grouping pushed down
.sayanswerpair > .bubble:last-of-type {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `clear: left`to your `.human` rule, and add  `clear: right` to you `.bot` rule

(EDITED AGAIN:)

Or add `clear:both;` to both rules, which will *always* put the next bubble lower than the the one before, also if it's on the opposite side.

Answer (score 1):

I created a solution with flexbox. With this code you can remove the pairs and set the bubbles in the right order to get a nice chat history. Checkout the following code:

```css
#conversationarea {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.bubble{
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px #B2B2B2;
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.bubble::before {
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  content: "\00a0";
  display: block;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 11px;
  transform:rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
  -moz-transform:rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
  -ms-transform:rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
  -o-transform:rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
  -webkit-transform:rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
  width:  20px;
}
.human {
  align-self:flex-start;
  margin: 5px 45px 5px 20px;
}
.human::before {
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px 0 rgba( 178, 178, 178, .4 );
  left: -9px;
}
.bot {
  align-self:flex-end;
  margin: 5px 20px 5px 45px;
}
.bot::before {
  box-shadow: 2px -2px 2px 0 rgba( 178, 178, 178, .4 );
  right: -9px;
}
```

```html
<div id="conversationarea" style="max-height:1024px;overflow:scroll;overflow-x: hidden;width:100%">
  <div class="humanphrase human bubble">Hi!</div>
  <div class="botphrase bot bubble" id="botphrase1">Hi it's great to see you!</div>
  <div class="humanphrase human bubble">How are you?</div>
  <div class="botphrase bot bubble" id="botphrase2">I'm very well. How are you doing?</div>
</div>
```

A working fiddle you can find here: https://jsfiddle.net/sebastianbrosch/htbjk5ns/1/

Comment: Great simple solution if you're not supporting ie10/9 and below. Another point to note is that there's less flexibility here for additional styling on a 'group' level because of the reduction in html elements. This should be simple enough to resolve with the missing clearfix.

Comment: Yes thats right. More information about the browser support you can find here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#browser-support